# Null Point Exception in JSP

Tags: database, jsp, exception, glassfish, nullpointerexception

When I try to add the data from a form to my DB it gives me an error as

> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   null 
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

```
This is my code

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String secondName = request.getParameter("secondName");
    String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String country = request.getParameter("country");
    int zip = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("zip"));
    int mobileNo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mobileNo"));
    int homePhone = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("homePhone"));
    String eMail = request.getParameter("eMail");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testproject", "root", "123456");
        Statement st = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO studentregform (firstName, secondName, gender, address, city, country, zip, mobile, homePhone, email) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        ps.setString(1, firstName);
        ps.setString(2, secondName);
        ps.setString(3, gender);
        ps.setString(4, address);
        ps.setString(5, city);
        ps.setString(6, country);
        ps.setInt(7, zip);
        ps.setInt(8, mobileNo);
        ps.setInt(9, homePhone);
        ps.setString(10, eMail);

        int result = ps.executeUpdate();




    } catch (Exception e) {
        //out.println("Data not inserted");
        throw new Error(e);
    }

%>
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: On a side note, I would *not* use integers for phone numbers ..

Comment: I'm in Srilanka. In here we use only 10 digit number as a phone number. In the mySQL I've created the relevant field as INT(11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that one of these 3 lines is giving you the problem;

```
int zip = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("zip"));
int mobileNo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mobileNo"));
int homePhone = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("homePhone"));
```

Are you sure they're all entirely numeric? In case one of them is empty, null, unset or has any kind of separators like `1-800-123-4567`, it can't be stored as a number and `Integer.ParseInt()` will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Edit: You say that your phone numbers are 10 digits and entirely numeric. Still, you're going to have problems since a Java `Integer` doesn't have that much precision. In fact, it cannot store any number larger than about 2 billion.

Comment: Yes they are numbers. Prior to submit the form I have validate the inputs via a javascrpit.

Comment: but previously I have done the same thing and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your information. The problem was in getting the parameters from the form. As well as the telephone numbers saved in the INT(11) without any errors. :) Thank you for kind help which was really needed when I was faced the dead end. KIT

Comment: @sumer Glad it helped, I googled Sri Lankan phone numbers, and the reason it works is that they all start with an area code that starts with 0, so all numbers are below one billion. In other words, an `Integer` is enough for this case.

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` seems a clear pointer to the fact that you're trying to convert a null `String` argument to an `Integer`, or that the `String` isn't a valid number.

Check for nulls/invalid integers in the following lines:

```
int zip = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("zip"));
int mobileNo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mobileNo"));
int homePhone = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("homePhone"));
```

Also, I'd reccomend using `Integer` instead, so that you can still pass them to the `PreparedStatement` in case they're null/can't be initialized due to incorrect format in its `String` form.

Comment: Thank you for your information. The problem was in getting the parameters from the form. As well as the telephone numbers saved in the INT(11) without any errors. :) Thank you for kind help which was really needed when I was faced the dead end. KIT